# How can I prune out all the unwanted chars from a string in one batch?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a mac address: `"22:33:44:12:34:56"` and I want to prune out all the semicolons.
If I do it without regular expressions it would be :

```
"22:33:44:12:34:56".replace(":","")
```

then  `"2233:44:12:34:56".replace(":","")` until I finish with all colons.

What is the regular expression that does this in a single batch?

Comment: A regular expression with a *global* flag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex flag `g` makes the global search:

```
"2233:44:12:34:56".replace(/:/g, "");
```

**REF:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: +1/ accept for being first

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu That's a good reason when you don't have another one :)

Comment: @dystroy Just edit it back :)

Comment: @dystroy Thanks for understanding I gave also +1 for your answer, you had practically the same answer just a few second late, unfortunately that was the only way I could decide :)

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu There is really no problem. VisioN and me are used to answer at the same time and he doesn't always win :)

Answer (score 3):

Do this :

```
"22:33:44:12:34:56".replace(/:/g,"")
```

The MDN explains [how you can use replace with a regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), and especially the `g` flag which makes the function replace all occurrences and not just the first one.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
'22:33:44:12:34:56'.split(':').join('')
```